# Check if exact word exists in an array

Tags: bash

I have an array that is a log and looks like this:

```
/home/user/
/home/user/xpto.txt
/home/user/bestmovieevah.avi
```

Each line is a position in the array.

Now i want to give an input, that is the name of a file and i want to check if the file exists in the log, but i want the exact word, for example if the input is "bestmovieevah.avi" the script should say that the file exists, if the input is for example "movie" or is a folder should say that the file doesn't exist.

Any tips?
I tried with grep and find and wasn't able to get to the solution yet.

EDIT: I guess the best approach is to compare 2 strings, see if the substring (file name) is the last element of the string (line of the array). Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
if [ $(echo "$log" | sed 's:.*/::' | grep "^$input\$") ]; then
  echo 'File exists in a log'
fi
```

where `$log` is array of log and `$input` is the input file name

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgrep -w`

```
fgrep -w "bestmovieevah.avi" log.txt
```